# Java 3rd party library demands List parameter, but it doesn't accept Kotlin's list or array

Tags: java, kotlin

I use some 3rd party library written in Java, and it has a class with following methods:

```java
    // D is generic type
    public void addSegments(D[] segmentData) {
        getControllerComponent().addSegments(segmentData);
    }

    public void addSegments(List<D> segmentData) {
        getControllerComponent().addSegments(segmentData);
    }
```

I am using Kotlin, in my case `D` type is `Long` and I am trying to set list of `Long`s,

```
val list: List<Long> = listOf(SportHandler.AMERICAN_FOOTBALL, SportHandler.FOOTBALL)
top_matches_segmented.addSegments( list )
```

but keep getting error:

`None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
    public open fun addSegments(p0: (Nothing..Array<out Nothing!>?)): Unit defined in xxx.SegmentedControl
    public open fun addSegments(p0: (Nothing..List<Nothing!>?)): Unit defined in xxx.SegmentedControl`

I also tried to provide array of Longs, but without success.

How can I provide list of Longs to this method to get this code work?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more code? It seems that `top_matches_segmented` has type `Something<Nothing>`, and it's hard to tell why (or is it even true) without the code. Also try to specify type of `top_matches_segmented` explicitly.

Comment: top_matches_segmented is reference to custom view provided by this library(https://github.com/RobertApikyan/SegmentedControl). I tried `(top_matches_segmented as SegmentedControl).addSegments( list )`, but received the same error again.

Comment: @Draško Could you past more code about create `top_matches_segmented ` instance? It seems like you are create `top_matches_segmented` without declaring a generic type.

Comment: Hi guys, you were right. I will write an explanation as an answer, I guess it can help someone  in the future.

Answer (score 2):

My error was that I didn't reference view as `SegmentedControl<D>` and compiler presumed that it is of type `SegmentedControl<Nothing>`. Following line solved the problem:

```
(top_matches_segmented  as SegmentedControl<Long>).addSegments( list )
```